# Installing Windows XP through Pendrive On windows 7 using Rufus or WintoFlash didn't get detected at boot time

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, usb-flash-drive

I'm currently in a situation where i want to install windows XP on my system which currently has windows 7 installed on it.
I've an `ISO` image of Windows XP sP3.I've tried `Rufus,WintoFlash even cmd method` but after each one of them when i try to boot from the Pen Drive the OS doesnt get detected.
Is there any work around for this? Pls help.

Thank YOU for your time.

**EDIT :** Researching on some blogs I've found that bc I'm using `windows 7` to make the bootable pendrive for `XP` is the reason it's not working. I should use a `windows XP platform` to make it bootable.
Any suggestions on that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no official application from Microsoft to create a bootable Windows XP USB flash drive installer, so I would burn a CD from the ISO file, and install from CD. If you do not have a CD drive on the PC, an external CD/DVD drive would work OK.

Make a bootable XP install disc from ISO on your Win7 OS by using Windows Explorer:

- Place a blank unformatted CD or DVD into your CD/DVD drive.
- Right click on the ISO or IMG file you want to use to burn a disc.
- Click Burn disc image.
- Next to Disc burner, click on the drop down arrow and select the CD/DVD drive with the blank disc you want to burn to.
- Check the Verify disc after burning option if you want Windows to verify the disc image after burning the disc (recommended!). Leave this option unchecked if you want to skip the verification. Note that you should skip verification if you are in a hurry, as this process requires additional time.
- When it finishes burning the disc image to disc, click the Close button.

Comment: So i cant install windows xp on my system?

Comment: No, but the USB flash drive method is not working, so the Burn-A-CD  method is known to be reliable, which is presented above.